# Which would be the best way to show purchased products in a dashboard?

Tags: e-commerce, dashboard, features, product, multiple-products

In my company we´ve created a site about rent and sell properties. Inside of it users can make different tasks, one of them is buy products. Like a really simple e-commerce.

Now we´re creating a dashboard where users are going to manage those products which have been purchased in the first site.
Users could perform tasks like: see the product details, date of purchase, price and other info.

Which will be the best way to show those product features?

I’ve seen these examples and I think they could work: 
[image]

[image]
What do you think?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first option only works if you only can buy one product, so you don't have to differentiate between products, right now it looks really confusing since I don't even know what I bought.

The second one works better, since I know what I purchased, when I purchased and how much I paid for it.

I really like Amazon's way of showing you purchase details, they display a lot of information but since they clustered that information well I'm basically just looking at what I want to look at, it's not overwhelming while basically telling me everything possible about an order.

[image]

Of course at the end it depends on how much information your customers want to see or need to see.